# Instantiated Object by a Lambda on the Thread is always resolved to null when compared

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda

In the following example, _instance is always resolving to null.  How should I be getting the value safely out of the thread?

```
class GenericThreadManager<TMyClass> where TMyClass : new()
    {

        private TMyClass _instance;
        private object synLock = new object();
        private Thread generalThread;

        public GenericThreadManager()
        {
            //wrapped code
            lock (this.synLock)
            {
                generalThread = new Thread(_instance => this._instance = new TMyClass());
                generalThread.Start();      // instantiates the object

                while (this._instance == null)  // allways compares to null even after 
                            // thread completes
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            //wrapped code
        }
```

Edits based on comments (thank you for the comments)

The while loop after the thread is just to debug / test if the thread is ever completing.

The context – is that this class instantiates an object that takes a long time to build (i.e. loading lots of data) on a thread.  This class then governs access to the object until the instantiation is complete.   Crudely I was doing this by checking if the object was `null`.

Although there might be better ways to solve the problem – I would like to understand where I’ve gone wrong in my understanding of threaded code / and Lambda’s.

Crudely – I understood `generalThread = new Thread(_instance => this._instance = new TMyClass());` to be setting the threadstart to the Lambda expression:

```
_instance => this._instance = new TMyClass()
```

I understand this expression creates a new instance of `TMyClass()` and place reference to that object in `_instance`.

I then understood that the threads my not be synchronised, so the value of `_instance` wouldn’t be reliably set – unless it was set to `volatile`.

With it set to `volatile` I get the following compile error:

```
Error   CS0677  'GenericThreadManager<TMyClass>._instance': a volatile field cannot be of the type 'TMyClass'
```

How do I resolve the above error or synchronise the threads to move the reference to the object to `_instance`.

@ Panagiotis Kanavos  could you explain why the each constructor would see a different lock.   The `GenericThreadManager` is making a private instance of `TMyClass`, a different object, in the `GenericThreadManager` constructor.  It locking on `synLock`, so in theory, any other methods on `GenericThreadManager` should block on the `lock (this.synLock)` if I understand correctly?

Comment: You aren't using thread-local storage so you aren't getting anything out of a thread. You are simply modifying a variable for another thread. That requires synchronization from *both* threads yet you aren't using any meaningful locking - synclock doesn't protect from *anything* - the lock object  is an instance field so each constructor will see a different one. The two threads aren't synchronized at all. Both the current thread and the new one try to access and modify `_instance` at the same time

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why not use the built-in mechanisms, like Task.Run, the TaskScheduler or even use the threadpool directly?

Comment: The *other* problem is that you use the same name for the thread parameter as the instance field `_instance`. If you don't want to pass any parameters, use `() => ` instead

Comment: Another problem - you are blocking the *constructor* yet the *lambda* is trying to access the captured object. Which isn't created yet. You never check that the new thread finished, so it may well have thrown an exception. I'll have to test this in a debugger to see what it actually does

Comment: I also fail to see the point of this construct. Maybe it's missing context, but why would you start a thread to create an object and then wait until that thread has completed?

Comment: If you wanted to create a value in a lazy manner you could use [Lazy< T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The value is simply cached, the loop doesn't see the update. Mark the `_instance` field as `volatile` to fix it (you'll also have to add the `where TMyClass : class` generic constraint). That said, as other comments have pointed out, there's probably much better ways to do whatever you're doing